# Real Analysis: Supremum Limit Points

Tags: real-analysis

Let B =  $\dfrac{n-1}{n} , n \in \mathbb N$.

Consider A = $(0,1)$ \ B.

Find the supremum, infimum, and limit points of A. Is A open, closed, or neither?

Solution Attempt: Sup $= 1$, inf $= 0$, The limit points are $1$ and $0$. The set is open.

Comment: Is $B$ the set of all points $\frac{n-1}{n}$ with $n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: Your answer for limit points is incorrect. Any $b\in B$ should be a limit point of $A$.

Comment: Yep, that's right, what is your question?

Comment: Can someone else confirm if my answer for limit points is correct or not?

Comment: @Dave.  Naw, it looks like a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers for supremum and infimum of $A$ are correct. The answer for limit points is also correct, assuming you are using the following definition:

$x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a **limit point** of $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ iff for every $r > 0$, the open interval $(x - r, x + r)$ intersects $A$ at a point other than $x$.

From this definition it should follow that every point interior to a set is also a limit point of that set. Since $A$ is an open set every $x \in A$ is interior to $A$, so every $x \in A$ is a limit point of $A$.

Other than $A$ itself, all elements of $B \cup \{0, 1\}$ are also limit points. So $[0, 1]$ is the set of all limit points of $A$.